# How to connect a Windows CE 5.0 device to a domain

Tags: networking, lan, domain, windows-ce

I am looking to buy a [Motorola MK500](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/interactive-kiosks/mk500-micro-kiosk.html) kiosk. This machine run on Windows CE 5.0

This kiosk will serve as a time and attendance system, logging scan time in a file. I know that CE [will not connect to a domain](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/microsoft.public.windowsce.platbuilder/vy9JqeOBhpY). So how can I either send the data to the domain, on retrieve the data from the domain.

If I connect this machine to the LAN, will I able to create a kind of FTP server?

Comment: Why do you need to connect it to the domain? If all you need is to transfer a file, set up an FTP server.

Comment: It might sound stupid, but If i setup a FTP Server on the CE machine, how will I access it from another computer in the domain.

Comment: I suppose you also have a network which your domain uses. Simply connect your device to that network and connect to it using its IP address.